# Pull a value from a dictionary

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I'm getting an error whenever I try to pull the temp value.  The error is:  TypeError: string indices must be integers

This is my code:

```
for item in data['main']:
    tempday=item['temp']
```

This is the API I am pulling from:

```
{
"coord": {},
"weather": [],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 53.2,
    "pressure": 1021,
    "humidity": 71,
    "temp_min": 44.6,
    "temp_max": 57.2
},
"visibility": 16093,
}
```

I want to get the "temp" value of 53.2.  What am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: try `data['main']['temp']`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`tempday=item['temp']` returns the key names. you need to iterate over to get values for all items. `data['main']`

```
for item in data['main']:
     data['main'][item]
```

Output

```
53.2 
1021
71
44.6
57.2
```

To get only one item

```
tempday=data['main']['temp']
```

Comment: This is not a correct solution. It will get all items: `temp`, `pressure`, `humidity`...

Answer (score 3):

Your code assumes that the content of `data['main']` is an `iterable` of `dict`s and is trying to get `temp` of all of those `dict`s.

Since it is just another single `dict`, you can drop the `for` loop and simply use

```
tempday=item['main']['temp']
```

Comment: Congrats. Your answer is at least -3 times better than the accepted one ;) Or at most, I don't know what the correct term should be.

Answer (score 0):

to explain the error, in general a dict iterates of its keys, the keys in this case are just strings. So doing:

```
for k in some_dict:
  # k is a string
  # some_dict[k] return the value of k in the dict
```